# Why rider light color scheme has dark autocomplete?

Tags: ide, jetbrains-ide, rider

I have switched dark scheme to the light, but autocomplite still dark

rider dark:

[image]

change color scheme

[image]

Approve changing of entire scheme

[image]

result autocompletion colors :(

[image]

I want normal autocomplete, I have checked color settings but didn't find how to achieve this, does anyone know?

Comment: Have you tried restart?

Comment: @IvanShakhov ha-ha, yes it helps, however switching back to dark mode also needs restart, looks like a rider bug. I wanted to have light theme in the day, because it is to use when sun is shine and dark in morning, evening. You can post and Answer if you want, otherwise I'll do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart Rider helps.

I have filled a bug report to JetBrains https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-33386
Please vote it.